# Two Django Sites on the same Apache Server - basic auth between the two giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, basic-authentication

I'm running two Django sites from Apache.  One is a demo page for an API so makes some API calls to the other authenticated by HTTP basic auth.  I also tried doing the same thing from the same site but I had the same problem.

When a request is made, Apache is giving a 403 error message/page.

The following is the necessary parts virtual host for the API server:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.567.890:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.example.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/lab-error.log

    WSGIScriptAlias / /webapps/lab/lab-wsgi.py

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /webapps/lab>
        <Files lab-wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the demo site virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.567.890:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName dvdemo.example.com
    ServerAlias dvdemo.example.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/demo-error.log

    WSGIScriptAlias / /webapps/lab/demo/Demo/wsgi.py

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /webapps/lab/demo/Demo>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It seems that, although I have `WSGIPassAuthorization On`, the basic auth is still being handled by Apache (Apache 403 page as opposed to JSON error from Django if the authentication failed).

If I make an identical request from my local machine to the API server, it works.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong, or what I should investigate further?  Thanks

Edit for clarification:
The API server has an OAuth2 API that I am attempting to create a demo page/site for. Requests to the API are successful if I make them via cURL or a different server, and only have issues when the request originates from the same server (different or same virtual host) as the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have subdirectories in Files directive. Use:

```
<Directory /webapps/lab/demo/Demo>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

The WSGIPassAuthorization is for passing credentials through needed for HTTP Basic authentication. It is generally highly unlikely that would be required for Django as it uses form based authentication. Are you definitely using something in Django for doing HTTP Basic authentication. Clarify what you are doing where to handle the HTTP Basic authentication.

Comment: Yes, Django is definitely using HTTP Basic Auth.  The API server has an OAuth2 API that I am attempting to create a demo page/site for.  Like I said, it works requesting the API endpoint from anywhere except on the same server.

Also I tried fixing up the Files directive like you mentioned as well, just in case, but no luck.